# How to make div rows fill available height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web page that contains multiple rows.  I want to be able to have those rows fill the available space equally (with a minimum height as well). The number of rows is also dynamic.

Here is the code:

```css
.outer {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="row">
    test 1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    test 2
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    test 3
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    test 4
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    test 5
  </div>
</div>
```

The colouring is just there so we can see what is happening.

Any help would be appreciated. The other questions on SO are not helping my specific case. Or at least I can't find one that does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. It creates columns instead of rows.

Comment: Then you can use flex-direction: column;

Comment: Also make sure the upper parent until body are all with height set to a fixed value or a percentage value. This way the whole screen will always be filled. In the other hand it wouldn't let you have normal scroll ability, you will have to use inner container scrolls.